# Upgrade Azure App Service to from .net core 3.1 to .net 6.0

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-6.0

We have an azure app service... which was created a few years ago using .net core 3.1... and when you navigate into the portal the .net version is blank.

[image]

If I query via the cli eg

az webapp config show --resource-group myresourcegroup --name myazureappservice

I get "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.0".

So I can change the value to .NET 6 via the UI but if I need to rollback I'll need to do so via the cli using

az webapp config set --name myazureappservice --resource-group myresourcegroup --net-framework-version "v4.0"

But then the drop is no longer blank but appears as:

[image]

So is that actually rolled back?? Pretty sure blank (.net core 3.1) != .net 4.8?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [MSDOC](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/netcore31/), .NET Core 3.1 version is out of support. That could be the reason you are seeing these changes in your web app.

I set the version of my web app to 3.1 to check the same:

[image]

.NET version was blank as you highlighted above:

[image]

But the other versions were available in the dropdown, we can opt the required version:

[image]

> So is that actually rolled back??

Yes, the version is getting reflected in the `.NET version` of Stack Settings. So, the roll back happened.

> Pretty sure blank (.NET Core 3.1) != .NET 4.8?!

Yes, you are right. [.NET Core 3.1](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/04/16/Announcing-.NET-Core-3.1-LTS-Generally-Available-on-App-Service.html) and [.NET 4.8](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/app-service-net-framework-48-support-now-available/) versions are different.

Comment: cheers...  the reason i was thinking --net-framework-version "v4.0" was because we actually have a few app services we need to upgrade... and when I do "az webapp config show" it returns v4.0... and drop down is blank... but when I roll back to this same value the drop down defaults to 4.8

The whole thing makes me nervous

Comment: `we actually have a few app services we need to upgrade` Are those linux web apps or windows. Do all the app services using .Net core 3.1?

Comment: they are windows.... yes all the app services using .net core 3.1....